# My Android Studio is giving me errors like:private method init was never used how do I fix this?

Tags: android

When I enter  private void init(){} in android studio I get an error saying Private method init() was never used. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I know this question probably seems very obvious but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you in advance. P.S I am just starting with android and have no background knowledge.

Comment: It says that for any method that's not being called from somewhere else. If you had a constructor in the same class that called init(), the warning would go away. But it's just a warning, you can ignore it.

Comment: It's just a warning. Also share the code. And the warning is pretty self-explanatory. You wrote something that you had not used. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a method or a variable and don't use it anywhere, you are going to take this warning (Is not an error, is a warning message)

For example (Same with methods):

```
int a = 0;
inb b = 1; //This variable is never used and cause a warning
System.out.println(a);
```